# python file was renamed, how to get 'rename time'

Tags: python, file-management

lets say that some files were renamed by Python script, is it possible to get this 'rename time' using Python (It can be seen in Far Manager)? (Windows)

It seems it is not possible through STAT, etc
Any ideas ?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with Python, so you should remove that tag

Comment: Why? I want to get file info ('rename time' using Python) ? I thought It is related to Python programming language

Comment: How can you see the time when the files were renamed using Far Manager?

Comment: No file system I'm aware of keeps track of file rename time. You are misinterpreting what you are seeing. The closest thing you can get is modification time of the directory containing the file; you won't be able to distinguish renamings of several files, though (or renamings from other kinds of directory modification).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python)

Comment: Wooble>>Not a duplicate, I asked about a way to get 'rename time', OS does not register it as 'modification', so modification is not the thing atzz>>Post this as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible, OS does not store such info about files. Answered by 'atzz' in comment

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to get the modification date of the file, it's this:

```
>>> import os
>>> import datetime
>>> stat = os.stat('/tmp/bacon')
>>> print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(stat.st_mtime)
2011-03-31 08:02:52.953873
```

Comment: No, unfortunately after file was renamed, it's modification date stays same